Bluetooth API: How can I detect that the user canceled the Mac OS permission modal?
Using the Web Bluetooth API in a React app, I can't figure out how to detect it when the user refuses permission.
EDIT: OR -- if you know how to connect to a Bluetooth device that is already in connected state on user's computer.
On Mac, there are two modals after attempting connection with a Bluetooth device. The first one is from navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice, where the user selects their device. The second is a permissions modal that says, "To reject the connection with the device, click cancel":

But even before you reply to this modal, or after clicking Cancel, the below code runs. No error is triggered, the microbit is in connected status (2), and the Chrome browser tab shows the Bluetooth symbol indicating connection.
But it's not really connected. It doesn't exist under Settings -> Bluetooth on the Mac OS, and the microbit does not respond to attempts to send commands.
Is there some clean way I can detect that the user has canceled the permissions modal? Finding nothing about this via GPT or Google.
  const connectMicrobit = async () => {
    try {
      const device = await navigator?.bluetooth?.requestDevice(
        bluetoothSearchOptions
      );
      if (!device) {
        throw new Error(
          "Unable to get device info. Unsupported browser likely."
        );
      }
      const server = await device.gatt.connect();
      const service = await server.getPrimaryService(MBIT_UART_SERVICE);
      const rxCharacteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(
        MBIT_UART_RX_CHARACTERISTIC
      );
      const txCharacteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(
        MBIT_UART_TX_CHARACTERISTIC
      );
      const uart = new MicroBitUART(rxCharacteristic, txCharacteristic);
      microbitUARTRef.current = uart;

      device.ongattserverdisconnected = () => {
        console.log("Microbit disconnected");
        disconnectMicrobit();
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("There was an error connecting to the Microbit:", error);
      disconnectMicrobit();
    }
  };


I found that Windows also has a permission modal, but it starts with an unobtrusive popup in the bottom right that the user has to click. In either case, I was not able to solve my issue cleanly. What I ended up doing is adding a five-second delay after device.gatt.connect() to give time for the permission to be given. Then, I changed that to be an alert modal where the user must confirm they gave permission, before continuing. Still not foolproof or clean, but it works.

When you click cancel on MacOS Bluetooth permission modal, do you get any error from await device.gatt.connect();?

@JackHsieh No error, see my post for more details~

I think you if you move:
      device.ongattserverdisconnected = () => {
        console.log("Microbit disconnected");
        disconnectMicrobit();
      };

before
const server = await device.gatt.connect();

Then you can tell if the user reject the system prompt.
I tried to reproduce a similar sequence using Logitech M720, I found that right after  device.gatt.connect(), the server is connected until the user reject the prompt. So if you have that GattServerDisconnected event handler registered beforehand, you can tell if the user reject the system prompt.
